# Calculate the number of students enrolled and finished within each month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to produce a cluster column chart with Month/Year as the x-axis and the number of enrolled and finished students within each month as y-axis, which would look like this (**navy: enrolled students, red: finished students; A: April, B: May, etc**):

[image]

In EXCEL, what I want to do would be simply put as:
**`Number of Enrolled = COUNTIFS('Student Enrolment Date', '>=01/04/2021', 'Student Enrolment Date', '<=01/04/2021')`**
**`Number of Completed = COUNTIFS('Student Finish Date', '>=01/04/2021', 'Student Finish Date', '<=01/04/2021')`**

Then use the calculated values to produce a visual.

The data example (let's call it **Student**) is as below:

[image]

I have also produced a date dimension as below:

[image]

I get confused about how to do this using DAX. If I connect Student['course start date'] with Date['Date'], and use Date['Year-Month'] as x-axis as below, then Power BI will count all students whose Student['course start date'] fall into each month. But because students is not necessarily get enrolled and finished in the same month, this method is apparently incorrect.

[image]

**My questions are**:

- I am now trying to count the date in Student['student enrolment date'] and Student['student finish date'] within each month using:

**Student Complete = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Student, Student[Status]="Complete" && Student[student enrolment date]>=DATE(2021, 4, 1) && Student[student enrolment date]<=DATE(2021, 4, 30) + 0))**

but DAX says this is not a correct formula, and I don't know how to make this formula calculate for each month. Could you please correct me?

- In my case, how to properly connect the date dimension to the Student dimension?

Answer (score 1):

I think your model is not ok and that's why your DAX is much more complicated than necessary.

Create a fact table that connects your dimensions.

e.g. factStudentEvents

```
StudentId   dateId      Enrollments Completions
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           20210413    1           0
1           20210620    0           1
2           20210427    1           0
```

Like this your DAX measures are very simple:

```
Completion Count = SUM(factStudentEvents[Completions])
Enrollment Count = SUM(factStudentEvents[Enrollments])
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late as I just got the chance to try this model. It works so well! Thanks for your patience to read through this super long question and your very helpful answer. 